# SSIS multiple table loads using single DFT

Tags: sql, ssis

I am new to the SSIS. I am trying to load multiple source tables from my staging database to corresponding destination table in the data warehouse. 
All the source table have diffrent number of column.
I am having 100 of SSIS package of 100 source Tables and 100 destination table.
I want to make single SSIS package to load all the 100 tables using single DFT.
I have a film aster table which containing the list of source table and destination table name, and input will be the filename , on the basis of filename my DFT will take the source and destination table and change the source and destination table using variable at run time dynamically.
Please suggest some ideas on above concern
Regards,
Vipin Jha

Answer (score 1):

DFTs are not dynamic -- they expect a certain schema for a source and destination at design time.  If the schema changes from what it was at design time, then validation errors will be thrown when you try to execute the package.

You could pursue using BIML to generate dataflows and packages with appropriate schemas:  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3094/introduction-to-business-intelligence-markup-language-biml-for-ssis/

However, I would also consider narrowing down what you are pulling from your source.  A data warehouse is not a copy of production.  In fact, you often only need, perhaps, 20% of what is in the source system to form a robust dimensional model, designed for reporting needs.

I would spend the time to reduce unneeded tables and columns, the data profiling task is very useful for this evaluation effort.  In the end, you will have a much more manageable and better performing ETL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the connection string property of the connection manager to dynamically set the table names at run time.

Comment: The connection manager does not specify a table - it connects to a server and, perhaps, a database.